# cURL php custom headers

Tags: php, curl, request-headers

I've tried using CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER with headers in the key value format

```
 $headers=['Accept' => 'application/json, text/plain, */*'];
```

and the other format

```
$header=['Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*'];
```

Sometimes one works while the other doesn't. I've seen people using both these formats and I can't figure out the difference. Can someone point out the difference between these two.

Comment: According to [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php), you should use string values, not key-value pairs.

Comment: > Sometimes one works while the other doesn't.

What do you mean "doesn't work ?" what do you do ? And what do you expect ?
Seconds option is correct.